# Cannot draw arrays after drawing elements

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, indexing

I have a huge, colored surface (over 1.3 million indices) thats drawn. This surface is indexed with "colored vertices". Whenever I try to draw non-buffered triangles after buffered triangles (colored vertices), the non-buffered triangles does not appear.

If I skip drawing the surface (buffered triangles) the non-buffered triangles draws as they should.

Drawing the buffered vertices:

```
// Bind array buffer
arrayBuffer->bind();

// Set position of vertices
int posLocation = program->attributeLocation("a_position");
program->enableAttributeArray(posLocation);
program->setAttributeBuffer(posLocation, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, sizeof(ColoredVertex));

// Set color of vertices
int colorLocation = program->attributeLocation("a_color");
program->enableAttributeArray(colorLocation);
program->setAttributeBuffer(colorLocation, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(QVector3D), 3, sizeof(ColoredVertex));
(GLfloat) 0.0);

// Bind index buffer and draw triangles
indexBuffer->bind();
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indicesCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Drawing the non-buffered vertices (faces):

```
if (faces.size() == 0) {
    qDebug("Tried to draw a textured block with no faces.");
    return;
}

int posLocation = program->attributeLocation("a_position");
int texcoordLocation = program->attributeLocation("a_texcoord");

// Draw faces
QHashIterator<Block::Side, Face> iterator(faces);
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Face face = iterator.next().value();

    program->setAttributeArray(posLocation, face.coordinates.constData());
    program->enableAttributeArray(posLocation);

    program->setAttributeArray(texcoordLocation, face.textureCoordinates.constData());
    program->enableAttributeArray(texcoordLocation);

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 6);
}
```

Comment: Did you ever `disableAttributeArray(colorLocation)`?

Comment: disableAttributeArray and releasing buffer was forgotten, and now its working. Thanks. Feel free to add any comments you may have on my code. I'm quite new to OpenGL (as you propably realized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be due to not disabling attribute arrays and releasing buffer objects properly. The following code works as it should.

Drawing the buffered vertices:

```
// Bind array buffer
arrayBuffer->bind();

int posLocation = program->attributeLocation("a_position");
int colorLocation = program->attributeLocation("a_color");

program->enableAttributeArray("a_position");
program->enableAttributeArray("a_color");

program->setAttributeBuffer(posLocation, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, sizeof(ColoredVertex));
program->setAttributeBuffer(colorLocation, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(QVector3D), 3, sizeof(ColoredVertex));

// Bind index buffer and draw triangles
indexBuffer->bind();
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indicesCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
indexBuffer->release();

program->disableAttributeArray(posLocation);
program->disableAttributeArray(colorLocation);

arrayBuffer->release();
```

Drawing the non-buffered vertices (faces):

```
if (faces.size() == 0) {
    qDebug("Tried to draw a textured block with no faces.");
    return;
}

int posLocation = program->attributeLocation("a_position");
int texcoordLocation = program->attributeLocation("a_texcoord");

program->enableAttributeArray(posLocation);
program->enableAttributeArray(posLocation);

program->enableAttributeArray(texcoordLocation);
program->enableAttributeArray(texcoordLocation);

// Draw faces
QHashIterator<Block::Side, Face> iterator(faces);
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Face face = iterator.next().value();

    program->setAttributeArray(posLocation, face.coordinates.constData());
    program->setAttributeArray(texcoordLocation, face.textureCoordinates.constData());

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, face.coordinates.size());
}

program->disableAttributeArray(posLocation);
program->disableAttributeArray(texcoordLocation);
```